# Can Stand Alone web2py Schedulers deployed on multiple servers (with different web2py versions) safely co-exist?

Tags: web2py

**Background Information for my question:**
I have an unusual use-case where I am running two different (but related) applications on an old version of web2py and a newer (recent) version.

eg.

"New Server" (an EC2 Instance running with Ubuntu) which runs a web application and a stand alone scheduler related to the web application on web2py version
2.14.6-stable+timestamp.2016.05.10.00.21.47
(Running on Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu), Python 2.7.12)

"Old Server" (an EC2 Instance running with Ubuntu) which runs a web application and a stand alone scheduler related to the web application on web2py version
2.9.5-stable+timestamp.2014.03.16.02.35.39
(Running on Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu), Python 2.7.6)

Originally the two apps were co-located on the "old" server, what I have done is migrated one of the apps to a much newer server. Medium to long term the old server will be upgraded and brought into line, but for reasons of risk aversion and short term priority I require that these two distinct versions "coexist" in that they point to the same DB infrastructure (a postgres RDS instance).

These two apps have associated stand alone gluon schedulers, which when co-located on the same "old" server functioned well for over a year. After the migration of one of the scheduler processes onto the newer server, to be co-located with the associated web application, I have experienced issues with the web2py scheduler (mostly manifested in the older version). The manifested issue was typically that the older versions stand alone scheduler would stop functioning, in effect locking up.

I have found that using distinct group names for the sets of tasks associated with each stand alone scheduler was helpful in getting the system to function when done in concert with what appeared to be a required modification in the new gluon scheduler to stop it from examining the worker that "belongs" to the "old" server version. This being due to an added column in the new scheduler_worker called "worker_stats" which is not populated by the "legacy" older gluon scheduler version.

My "fix/hack" for the new behaviour is described by following diff output:

    `@@ -1083,7 +1081,7 @@ class Scheduler(MetaScheduler):
    """
    sw, st, sd = db.scheduler_worker, db.scheduler_task, db.scheduler_task_deps
    now = self.now()
    -        all_workers = db((sw.status == ACTIVE) & (sw.group_names == "|myNewGroupName|")).select()
    +        all_workers = db(sw.status == ACTIVE).select()
    # build workers as dict of groups
    wkgroups = {}
         for w in all_workers:`

Note: I also ensured the old scheduler was running with group_name "myOldGroupName" ... this appeared necessary to ensure no lock up (originally I defaulted the old one to "main"... but I suspect this also caused conflict

**Initial Request for community feedback (possibly to be followed by further elaboration by myself and provision of technical details, pending responses and any requests for such):**

Is the gluon scheduler supposed to be fully backward compatible ?

Is the gluon scheduler backward compatible when it needs to "co-exist" with another "version" in real time using the same DB tables?

Is it "safe" to mix old and new web2py versions running over the same shared DB tables ?

NOTE: I can confirm that with all actions taken so far, even if scheduling is started and runs for  few hours, it appears to eventually stall for ALL tasks, leaving no tasks able to run and ALL tasks in queued state.... as though entire scheduler mechanism is locked up over both servers stand alone scheduler instances (even though in theory the tasks and associated workers are unrelated (? or are they ?)

Comment: BTW: IF I stop the new stand alone scheuler and leave the old one activated, the old scheduler starts working OK... and vice versa.

Comment: In the end I split the schedulers across two different DB schema's (thereby decoupling the config) and its all working again. This is fine for my use case (where the applications are distinct in terms of the tasks being scheduled) but I wonder what happens if you have a load balancing situation with multiple servers and the same tasks potentialy running in a load balanced manner over them ?

Comment: BTW.... Thanks to everyone who worked to create web2py ! its an awesome infrastructure for web development.